# How to vertically centre the cursor in the line height?

Tags: cursor

Is there a way to align the mid of the cursor with the baseline of the font? E. g.,

[image]

Here I have adjusted the cursor height to be approximately 1/2 the line height via,

```lisp
(setq-default cursor-type '(hbar . 10))
```

And the cursor is at a pipe character `|`. I have enlarged the font size via multiple invocations of `C-x =` for clarity.

Is there a way to now vertically align the cursor in the height of the line?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Okay--I added more details.

Comment: In which case I suggest you start with the function `x_draw_bar_cursor` in `src/xterm.c` and the `else /* HBAR_CURSOR */` section in particular.  It sets `width = min (row->height, width);` and then calls `x_fill_rectangle` with the `height` argument set to that `width` value.

Comment: For clarity: Changing that means editing the C code and recompiling Emacs.

Comment: I was looking for more of a `init.el` configuration tweak...

Comment: No doubt, but I don't think anything suitable is exposed to lisp.  WRT the call to `x_fill_rectangle` it occurs to me that it's more the starting coordinates than the height which are of import.  My best suggestion is to read the C code, figure out exactly which code path is being used in your case, and figure out the easiest way to change it.  Someone might know differently, but my current take is that you'll be writing C code and recompiling Emacs to achieve this.